# Powershell AD Module Expiration date different from ADUC

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I stuck with a problem. I want to check my users' expiration date with Powershell, but the thing is the dates are different from the ADUC (Active Directory - Users and Computers). My problem is when I run the query to harvest the expiration dates it shows me randomly different values from the GUI and we generally use the GUI to set the dates, so it completely wrong. I couldn't even found a pattern among the differences, somewhere is just 1-2 hours (and this makes sense because it can change the date if this occurs around midnight) and somewhere 24 hours. This is really annoying thing because I don't know what can I do. So, what I have tried so far:

1. I tried to use the AccountExpires attribute and convert it in many ways
2. I tried to handle the difference manually, but because the differences are not equal so it didn`t help
3. Convert the date to local time with ToLocalTime() method
4. I`ve read many articles on google...

Here is a couple of examples:

**1.**
Here the date should be 2021.05.26.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
$myUser | Select Name, AccountExpirationDate, @{l="ExpDate"; e={([datetime]$_.AccountExpires).AddYears(1600)}}

Name      AccountExpirationDate ExpDate             
----      --------------------- -------             
Joci Kuka 2021.05.27. 0:00:00   2022.05.26. 22:00:00
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**2.**
Here the date should be 2022.02.10.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
$my_user | Select Name, AccountExpirationDate, @{l="ExpDate"; e={([datetime]$_.AccountExpires).AddYears(1600)}}

Name             AccountExpirationDate ExpDate
----             --------------------- -------
NotaValid Name 2022.02.11. 10:48:20  2022.02.11. 9:48:20
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

If somebody could, please help me!

Thank you in advance!

Regards,
Jozsef Odor

Comment: This might answer your question: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a968bd92-b0e3-4638-9064-928f732e087c/different-dates-of-an-ad-expired-account?forum=winserverDS

Answer (score 0):

Times in AD are stored in a common Windows format often known as a filetime or NT time epoch, which is a 64-bit integer containing the number of 100 nanosecond periods of time since Jan 1, 1601 (UTC). [The Active Directory schema documents make this clear](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-accountexpires).

Fortunately, there is a common function to convert from a filetime to a local datetime, [`DateTime.FromFileTime()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.fromfiletime?view=net-5.0). To do the proper conversion, do it like so:

```
$myUser | Select Name, AccountExpirationDate, @{l="ExpDate"; e={[datetime]::FromFileTime($_.AccountExpires)}}
```

That is basically how AD itself actually determines when expirations happen.

ADUC does do some silent manupulation, too. When you set an expiration date to 2021-04-26 in ADUC, the value in AD should be 2021-04-27 00:00:00 local time which is then converted to a UTC FileTime (with a function such as `DateTime.ToFileTime(dateTime)`). That way it expires at the end of the day on 4 Apr 2021.

If you are still seeing time variations, my guess would be either that the user who set the expiration date was in a different time zone, the expiration date was set during daylight saving time (or not during daylight saving time), or AD lies and isn't really using UTC.